# How to count elements and take attribut of first?

Tags: jquery, each

I want to count all img elements and take attribute (alt) of FIRST of it.
My try:

```
$('img').each(function(index) {
    /* need count and take forst */
    if(index=0){
    var objid = $(this).attr('alt');
    }
});
```

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $images = $('img');
var imgCount = $images.length;
var altAttrOfFirst = $images.first().attr('alt');
```

Comment: Blank as blank. May be because i use it in ajax query?

Comment: `altAttrOfFirst` can be blank but what do you see for `imgCount`. Is it 0?

Comment: imgCount returns 19 (but i have 7 img tags)

Comment: jQuery will find all the `img` elements if you use "img" selector. If you want to find within any container the you should speicfy that.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var $img=  $('img');
 var count = $img.length;
 var attr = $img.first().attr('alt');
```

Comment: `$img[0]` gives a DOM element. Use `first()` or `eq(0)`.